# $2\sin x\cos x\ge 1 - \cos2x$ what is $x_1+x_2$

Tags: trigonometry

I get

$2\sin^2x-2\sin x\cos x\le 0$

$2\sin x =0$ or $\sin x=\cos x$

$x=2\pi n$

$x=\pi + 2\pi n$

$x=\pi/4 + \pi n$

For interval $ [\pi,2\pi]$
I get answer
$x=\pi/4 + \pi$
But its wrong why?

The options are 9/4 pi, 3pi, 13/4 pi, 14/4 pi, 15/4 pi

Comment: Where did you get the extra $2$ in your first equation? You could also change to double-angles, $2\sin(2x)\ge 1+\cos(2x)\iff \sqrt3\sin(2x+a)\ge 1$ with a phase angle $a$ corresponding to the point $(2,-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

You have

$$
2\sin x\cos x-\sin^2x\ge 0
$$

if $\sin x=0$ you have a solution otherwise you can divide the inequality by $\sin^2x$ and end up with an inequality only in $\tan$.

Hope this helped

Comment: what do you mean, divide inequality by sin^2x?

Comment: I mean that divide both sides of the inequality by $\sin^2x$, observe that this is always positive so you can do this without any major consequence.

Comment: i edited the question, its cos2x

Comment: thats true, I used the fact that $\cos2x=\cos^2x-\sin^2x$

Comment: 1-cos2x is 2sin^2x

Comment: yes, it indeed is

Comment: guess tanx = 1?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99915/discussion-between-vinyl-cape-jawa-and-lifeforbetter).

Comment: sorry i messed up a the fraction, the resulting inequality is in $\cot$